# Point only subdomain to new host provider

Tags: php, wordpress, dns, subdomain

I'm hosting my static portfolio on Netlify but my blog is built on Wordpress.

I'm wondering is there a way to point a subdomain "blog.example.com" to a wordpress host like GetLark without moving the rest of the site over too?

I thought I'd just be able to add new A records but GetLark only seems to provide nameservers.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's provider-specific. Some allow you to keep your domain & DNS externally and point entries to their servers, some don't. Ask yours if they do.

Answer (score 0):

You can create NS records for the subdomain like this in the example.com DNS zone:

```
 blog.example.com NS nsX.GetLark-server.com.
```

This way only blog.example.com will be managed by nsX.GetLark-server.com. It should work, because all queries about blog.example.com will go to nsX.GetLark-server.com.